# Array constants initialization in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Consider below sample code in java which wants to search which task are allowed in the action

```
public boolean acceptableTaskForAction(String taskName,String actionName) {


    String[] allowedActions;
    switch (taskName){
    case "Payment" :
        allowedActions = { "full-payment", "bill-payment"};

    case "Transfer" :
        allowedActions = { "transfer-to-other", "tarnsfer-to-own"};

    }

    for (String action : allowedActions){
        if (actionName.equals(action)){
            return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you know the above will not compile as `Array constants can only be used in initializers`

I thought of defining different parameters so it will be

```
public boolean acceptableTaskForAction(String taskName,String actionName) {


    String[] allowedActionsForPayment= { "full-payment", "payment"};
    String[] allowedActionsForTransfer= { "transfer-to-other", "tarnsfer-to-own"};
    String[] allowedActions={};
    switch (taskName){
    case "Payment" :
        allowedActions = allowedActionsForPayment;

    case "Transfer" :
        allowedActions = allowedActionsForTransfer;

    }

    for (String action : allowedActions){
        if (actionName.equals(action)){
            return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Do you think of other solutions!?
What do you think is the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this your case

```
String[] allowedActions;
switch (taskName){
case "Payment" :
    allowedActions = new String[] { "full-payment", "bill-payment"};
    break;
case "Transfer" :
    allowedActions = new String[] { "transfer-to-other", "tarnsfer-to-own"};
    break;
}
```

*Array constants can only be used in initializers*, but you can always create a new `String[]` and assign it as and when required.

Comment: Will the assignment statement above for allowedActions result in new allocations for each of the String elements of the array at run time, or only a new allocation for the String array itself (with the String elements merely referencing the String constants "full-payment" etc., which were created at compile time)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Array` you can use `ArrayList` safely for your requirement!

```
List<String> allowedActions = new ArrayList<String>();
switch (taskName){
    case "Payment" :
        allowedActions.add("full-payment");
        allowedActions.add("payment");
        break;
    case "Transfer" :
        allowedActions.add("transfer-to-other");
        allowedActions.add("tarnsfer-to-own");
        break;
    }
return allowedActions.contains(actionName);
```